# How to stay on div after toggle jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".req_sent").hover(function () {
        $(".drop").toggle("hover");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="profile_btnn">
    <button type="submit" name="req_sent" class="btnplus req_sent">Sent</button>
</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none;">
 <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

I have a simple `button` i.e. `Sent`. Now, What I actually want when I hover on `Sent` button then It show `div` i.e. `<div class="drop">` but it hide when I move cursor from `Sent` button to `<div class="drop">`.

Now, I want stay on `<div class="drop">` when hover on `Sent` if I remove my mouse from `<div class="drop">` it will hide again. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: add `hover` function for `drop` div as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code where show `drop` when hover on `sent` button. On hover of `drop` do nothing but hide it when you leave `drop`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".req_sent").hover(function(){
            $(".drop").show();
        });
        $(".drop").hover(function(){
            //do nothing
        }, function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile_btnn">
    <button type="submit" name="req_sent" class="btnplus req_sent">Sent</button>
</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none;">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `.drop` actually remains displayed as soon as you hover out from `Sent` to body.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<div class="profile_btnn">
    <button type="submit" name="req_sent" class="btnplus req_sent">Sent</button>
    <div class="drop" style="display:none;">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".profile_btnn").hover(function(){
     $(".drop").toggle("hover");
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: might wanna target `$(this).find('.drop').toggle("hover");` so that every `.drop` class doesn't expand when doing this

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep, visible `div` event mouse out from `Sent` button. And hide when its mouse over on `div`

**Just don't use `toggle()` and apply `show()` to get it done.**

Please check below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".req_sent").hover(function () {
        $(".drop").show('slow');
    });
    $(".drop").hover(function () {
        $(".drop").hide('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="profile_btnn">
    <button type="submit" name="req_sent" class="btnplus req_sent">Sent</button>
</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none;">
 <p>hello</p>
</div>
```